# sklearn Lasso vs LassoCV

Tags: scikit-learn

I have the following code for finding the best alpha in Lasso - first I am using an explicit loop to fit `Lasso` for each alpha and in the second approach I am using `LassoCV`. I was expecting that the scores of the two approaches would be the same but it is not the case. Can someone help me out? Thank you.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LassoCV
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn import datasets

X, y = datasets.load_diabetes(return_X_y=True)
print(X.shape, y.shape)
X, y = X[:150], y[:150]
print(X.shape, y.shape)

alphas = np.logspace(-4, -0.5, 5)

# Explicit looping
out_k_fold = KFold(3, shuffle=False)
in_k_fold = KFold(3, shuffle=False)
for (calib, test) in out_k_fold.split(X, y):
    X_calib, y_calib = X[calib], y[calib]
    X_test, y_test = X[test], y[test]
    score_matrix = np.zeros((3, len(alphas)), dtype=np.float64)
    for (i_split, (train, valid)) in enumerate(in_k_fold.split(X_calib, y_calib)):
        X_train, y_train = X_calib[train], y_calib[train]
        X_valid, y_valid = X_calib[valid], y_calib[valid]
        for i_alpha, alpha in enumerate(alphas):
            lasso = Lasso(random_state=0, max_iter=10000, alpha=alpha)
            lasso.fit(X_train, y_train)
            score = lasso.score(X_test, y_test)
            score_matrix[i_split, i_alpha] = score
    print(score_matrix)
    print(np.mean(score_matrix, axis=0))
    print(alphas)
    break

# Using LassoCV
out_k_fold = KFold(3, shuffle=False)
in_k_fold = KFold(3, shuffle=False)
for (calib, test) in out_k_fold.split(X, y):
    X_calib, y_calib = X[calib], y[calib]
    X_test, y_test = X[test], y[test]
    lasso_cv = LassoCV(alphas=alphas, random_state=0, max_iter=10000, cv=in_k_fold)
    lasso_cv.fit(X_calib, y_calib)
    print(lasso_cv.alpha_, lasso_cv.score(X_test, y_test))
    break
```

Answer (score 1):

1. In the explicit looping approach the scores (and the best score from it) is being found using models trained on `X_train`.
2. In the `LassoCV` approach the score is computed from the model built on `X_calib` (the full dataset) using the best alpha found during the cross-validation.

I missed the (obvious?) fact that the final model in `LassoCV` is found using the "full" `X_calib` dataset and not the best among the models trained on `X_train`.